# Is it possible to create a iPhone / iPad usb video input cable

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, usb

Is it feasibly (by feasible, I mean would apple allow) To create a piece of hardware that would allow the USB cable to act as a video input. I have not been able to find anything like this on the market. I know that it's possible to stream video through WIFI locally, but from what I have read it's quite laggy. I also know that in order to create hardware you need a MFi membership, but I'm note even sure if apple would allow this sort of functionality.

Comment: You should ask Apple. Anything anyone answers here is going to be anecdotal. This is not the correct forum for this kind of question, emailing apple's MFi evangelist is a much better place to start.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is literally asking the dev forum if Apple are going to let him build a specific type of hardware extension to the iOS Device line.

Comment: My question is if it's possible, perhaps it's more of a hardware question.

Comment: Nobody knows if it's possible except Apple. With hardware, it may be physically possible but they may not let you do it. You simply need to ask their MFi evangelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes it is possible, but in this case for Apple iPhone and iPad is not. USB protocol has a master/slave architecture, for example a Windows PC is the host, while the USB device is the slave. When the USB device is plugged in, the host is informed about the capabilities of the device through the USB descriptor, later the host will request/send abstract USB packets that may be audio, video, files, whatever.

In your case, for iPhone and iPad the host feature is disabled, they may be only clients for other hosts - a PC for instance. It's a marketing decision, because people would be able to buy cheap external storage, instead of more expensive devices or cloud storage. As a consequence your video streaming device which would be a client will not work.

There are two workarounds: one would be to crack Apple iPhone, iPad software, so you cannot build a business on top of it. The second one, would be that your USB video cable to be smart enough (through an embedded controller) to act as a host with the iPhone, iPad, and would a second software on the Apple device to talk with your hardware. It's not so easy, but maybe it worth the effort, who knows...

Answer (score 1):

I know it is the old thread but my answer can be usefull for someone to make further investigation...eventually to provide some schematic, etc. Definitely IT IS POSSIBLE and I have already tried it. The DJI Lightbridge device used mainly for the UAV cameras and video transmission has an USB port and their own aplication for Android/iOS (iPhone) that can transmit the video and to view/record pictures from camera on tablets or phones. The phone acts as FPV monitor in that case. I have used it with the Android tablet and also with the iPhone 5s and it works great!